# Clean way to handle future and option

Tags: scala

My code block looks like this currently which seems ugly:

```
for {
  maybeUser <- getUser(1)
} yield {
  if (maybeUser.isDefined) {
     someFunction1(maybeUser.get)
  } else None
}
```

Where getUser looks like:

```
def getUser(id: Int): Future[Option[user]]
```

Comment: `getUser(1).map(_.flatMap(someFunction1))`

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to something like:

```
for {
  maybeUser <- getUser(1)
} yield {
  maybeUser.map(someFunction1)
}
```

This will yield an `Option[T]` (where `T` is the return type of `someFunction1`)  which should be what you want.

For a great summary of `Option` patterns I can't recommend this article highly enough: [Your Options Don't Match](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/06/15/idiomatic-scala-your-options-do-not-match/)

Comment: you want `.flatMap`, not `.map`

Comment: Wouldn't a `map` replicate OP's code snippet? It looks like he wants to yield an `Option[???]`

Comment: Or is `maybeUser` a `Future[Option[User]]`? I thought the generator would unwrap the future

Comment: He wants to yield an `Option[User]`, but you are yielding an `Option[Option[User]]`. `mayberUser` is `Option[User]`, but `someFunction` returns `Option[User]` as well.

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't sure about the signature of `someFunction1` so I left it general: "This will yield an `Option[T]` (where `T` is the return type of `someFunction1`)"

Comment: I know. Just saying it's clear what `someFunction1` returns from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (maybeUser <- getUser(1);
     user <- maybeUser) yield someFunction1(user)
```

Assuming someFunction1(user) returns an Option something (otherwise call Some(someFunction1(user))

Comment: Won't work.. xD It would translate to `future.flatMap(option.map(...))` but he needs `future.map(option.map(...))`.

Comment: Yeah I am getting an error.  Found:  Option[Future[Option[User]]] required Future[Option[User]]

Answer (score -1):

You can try a more readable one.

```
val mayBe = getUser(1)
(for {
     m <- maybe
     if m.isDefined
   } yield m.get //Seq(m.get)
 ).recover {
    _=> ??? //Seq.empty[MType]
 }
```